# Ansible: case statement assign a value to variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to assign a value to the `environment` variable, based on the hostname pattern of the server, but it fails with the below error.

can someone please suggest?

```
  - name: Set dit . 
    set_fact: environment= "dit"
    when: "{{ anisible_hostname }} == wpad*"

  - name: Set sit.
    set_fact: bootstrap_environment= "sit"
    when: "{{ anisible_hostname }} == wpas*"

  - name: Set prod.
    set_fact: bootstrap_environment= "prod"
    when: "{{ anisible_hostname }} == wpap*" || "{{ anisible_hostname }} == rpap*"
```

here is the error message.

```
TASK [Set sit.] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ anisible_hostname }} == wpas*
fatal: [wpasaser01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ anisible_hostname }} == wpas*' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ anisible_hostname }} == wpas*): 'anisible_hostname' is undefined\n
\nThe error appears to be in 'bootstrap.yml': line 23, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Set sit.\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

> *"conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }}"*

See the example below how to test a pattern

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: OK
      loop:
        - wpad-01
        - wpad-02
        - xyz
      when: item is match("^wpad(.*)$")
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=wpad-01) => 
  msg: OK
ok: [localhost] => (item=wpad-02) => 
  msg: OK
skipping: [localhost] => (item=xyz)
```

---

Try the code below

```yaml
  - name: Set dit. 
    set_fact:
      environment: "dit"
    when: ansible_hostname is match("^wpad(.*)$")

  - name: Set sit.
    set_fact:
      bootstrap_environment: "sit"
    when: ansible_hostname is match("^wpas(.*)$")

  - name: Set prod.
    set_fact:
      bootstrap_environment: "prod"
    when: ansible_hostname is match("^wpap(.*)$") or
          ansible_hostname is match("^rpap(.*)$")
```

---

Simplify the code. Put the logic into a dictionary, instead of "hard-wired" conditions, e.g

```yaml
- hosts: wpad-01,rpap-02,xyz
  vars:
    environtments:
      - {pattern: wpad, env: dit}
      - {pattern: wpas, env: sit}
      - {pattern: wpap, env: prod}
      - {pattern: rpap, env: prod}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        env: "{{ _list.0|default('UNDEFINED') }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ environtments|
                   selectattr('pattern', 'in', inventory_hostname)|
                   map(attribute='env')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: env
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [wpad-01] => 
  env: dit
ok: [rpap-02] => 
  env: prod
ok: [xyz] => 
  env: UNDEFINED
```